# Customers Can't Checkout Magento ver. 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a random where some of my customers are unable to checkout.

They claim they login to their account enter billing address, click continue and nothing happens. The onepage checkout won't move on to the next step.

I have been unable to duplicate the issue. Some users have no problems and I don't see anything in the error logs.

Any idea what this may be?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you check magento log files?